# all time result is same in send_from_diretory

Tags: python, api, flask, pytest

when i run this code , it runs fine.
But when i changed a filename from happy_flow_logs.txt to 1.txt ,always it returns me to happy_flow_logs.txt file. how can i change a response according to updated filename.

```
from flask import Flask, send_file, make_response, send_from_directory

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def download():
try:
    print("calling api")
    return send_from_directory(directory="/home/einfochips/Desktop/python/exercise", filename="happy_flow_logs.txt")
except FileNotFoundError as e:
    return e.strerror

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
    print("done")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

same as the send_file()
we can use:

```
return send_from_directory(directory ="/home/einfochips/Desktop/python/exercise",
                                filename = "happy_flow_logs.txt",
                                as_attachment = True,
                                cache_timeout = 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is you close the running flask app?

you can reference the `https://www.reddit.com/r/flask/comments/36ngb7/af_how_can_i_interrupt_an_infinite_while_loop_on/` to find method interrupt the flask app and run again.

If the cache issue, please check the `cache_timeout` option in the  `send_from_directory()` method.

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.send_from_directory

Comment: yes , i closed the flask app , in fact i restarted my system , but still the cache is stored, and i  get the older file .

Comment: i think ,you still didn't get my question , my cose wasn't going in infinite loops , but when i update my code like file name change , it doesn't reflect in the output, all time older output , i am getting.